# Excel ROW() or COLUMN() value as input to OFFSET() function causes error

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to get a reference to an array offset by a number of columns that depends on the ROW number of a given cell.  But the result of this:
=OFFSET(range_name, 0, ROW())
is an error.  Can anyone tell me why and/or offer a suggestion?

Update: it appears that when a range is used as the first argument, the row argument value is converted to an array, with unexpected results.  I got what I needed this way: =OFFSET(range_name, 0, MIN(ROW())).  Still, it's rather inconvenient, especially when incorporated into larger formulas.  I'd be grateful for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OFFSET only takes a cell for the first argument, not a range, so if your range were from B12:B30, you would write `=OFFSET(B12,0,ROW())`